# Positioning CSS callboxes to align properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting following items (shown below) to align: basically, a small user avatar and some stats appears to the left of the main body of text by that user, as well as any additional elements below.  I have set my whole page to have Bootstrap's `<div class="container">` , and so in other words the user avatar could be aligned to the left most of the page set by the `container` class, with the main elements coming to the right.  I am having trouble getting any of the "additional elements" to line up, and it appears using `vertical-align:text-top` in my classes are not working.. thanks for your help!

Desired output...

```
 ----   -------------------------------
|user| |main text ...                  |
|ava-| |                               |
|tar | |                               |
 ----  |                               |
       |                               |
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
       |additional elements...         |
        -------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you include the actual markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <img id="avatar" src="" />
    <div id="rightDiv">
        <div id="mainText">
        </div>
        <div id="elements">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#avatar
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
}
#rightDiv
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/pxY6c/